# Update taskbar icon for UWP application at runtime

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

How do I update the taskbar icon dynamically for a UWP app? I am looking to achieve something like Skype does by updating the icon to show your status. I want to be able to show the state of my app at all times even when it is minimized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the MSDN topic that describes how to make notification badges appear on your app's taskbar icon (and in the lower-right corner of its start tile):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-badges

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realise these were applicable to the taskbar icon. Just what I wanted

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to copy the example code to here? These pages tend to change their URL every few years or so.